# How to properly bind kendo multiselect with knockout using ajax

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, kendo-ui, datasource, multi-select

I've been working on this for days and finally have a partially working solution, but it doesnt feel quite right.  In fact, i'm not sure any of this is right.

My problem is three fold:

1. generating the filter value in the read function doesnt seem right. I feel like i should be able to bind the multiselects text value or something and use that in the function,
2. the filter stops processing if i keep typing characters beyond the minLength setting. If i type "cha" the ds fetches "Charles" and "Chad".  But if i continue typing and enter "chad", the filter still shows "Charles".
3. names already selected in the "value" property continue to display in subsequent searches.  So if i select "Charles", then i select "Tim", then i type "cha", "Charles" will show up on the list again.  But because he's already selected he should not appear on the list.

I'm using the kendo-knockout js, here's what i have so far:

```html
<select data-bind="kendoMultiSelect: { dataSource: ds, autoBind: false, change:'filterTypeOnChanged', search: relatesSearch, minLength: 3, filter:'contains', value: selectedPersons, dataTextField:'PersonName'}"></select>
```

And here's the datasource (ds) that i'm binding to.  (it's in typescript, so hopefully that wont hang anybody up).

```js
        ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true
            , type: 'json'
            , transport: {
                read: (options) => {
                    var srch: string;
                     debugger;
                   if (options.data[0] != undefined)
                        srch = options.data[0].value;
                    else
                        srch = options.data.filter.filters[0].value;


                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/Person/GetPersons",
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        data: JSON.stringify({ textToBeSearched: srch }),
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                        processData: false,
                        success: result => {
                            options.success(result.data);
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            debugger;
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but in my case (javascript) I set transport.read with the url and dataType properties. I don't need the ajax request explicit declaration as you have in your question. I think the call is made asynchonosly but right after page load. I then have the fetch method where I store the data in an extended property from the model. I can then compare the data chosen in the multiselect with the data that came from the server. It's not 100% asynchronous, but it works in my case.